# How can I localize a URL in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, localization, url, config

`UrlHelper::getUrl()` doesn't appear to take the current locale ID into account when generating a URL. Absolute URLs are fine as it handles that but is there a best practice way to localize relative Urls such as `/foo/bar` or `foo/bar`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [UrlHelper::getSiteUrl()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/UrlHelper#getSiteUrl-detail) instead, which does have a `$localeId` argument, for generating a URL relative to a given locale’s base URL (per the [siteUrl](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#siteUrl) config setting).

So if your `siteUrl` config setting is set to:

```php
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en' => 'http://example.com/',
    'de' => 'http://example.com/de/',
)
```

and you do this:

```php
UrlHelper::getSiteUrl('foo/bar', null, null, 'de');
```

it will return this:

```php
http://example.com/de/foo/bar
```

(Regardless of which site you call it from.)

UrlHelper::getSiteUrl() is also available to Twig templates via a `siteUrl()` global function:

```php
{{ siteUrl('foo/bar', null, null, 'de') }}
```